# Why there is no `static_if` in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I wonder why such a natural thing like `static_if` did not manage to get into C++11? Some people object that using inheritance or template specialization we could achieve demanded results BUT:

Why don't we have a simple `static_if` for simple situations when one doesn't want to bloat up the source code with all that?

Comment: What compiler are you using that doesn't remove the dead code in `if (false) { ... } else { ... }`? Or do you mean the dead code isn't valid C++?

Comment: There is `enable_if`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: @hvd What about variable declaration?

Comment: Because. Try to google about it, something like "Static if: i had a hammer" etc.

Comment: @ForEveR How that answers that question? I know that video very well.

Comment: Why isn't foo in C++? Because one of these: a) nobody thought of it b) nobody finished proposing and standardizing it in time c) there was a disagreement

Comment: @Martin What variable declaration?

Comment: @hvd How do you conditionally declare a variable depending on a template `bool` argument?

Comment: @Martin Now I see what you mean. That, IMO, is not at all clear from your question.

Comment: @Pubby, We should have that as a FAQ. Enough people actually ask questions along those lines.

Comment: @Martin Pubby has actually given the correct answer. You might not like it but that is the same response that you’ll get for committee members to this sort of questions (and yes, I’m speaking from experience)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suppose the commitee was short of time to discuss this feature so they decide to delay it after C++11. Anyway proposal is here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3329.pdf

Comment: @Martin Have you seen [Static If I Had a Hammer](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Static-If-I-Had-a-Hammer)?   Or [Alexandrescu, Meyers, Sutter: On Static If, C++11 in 2012, Modern Libraries, and Metaprogramming](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Alexandrescu-Meyers-Sutter-On-Static-If-C11-in-2012-Modern-Libraries-and-Metaprogramming)? If I remember well, your question is answered in the latter and it will probably part of a future C++ standard (static if as "concepts lite").

Comment: @Martin You sound exasperated yet got an answer within 6 minutes.

Comment: FWIW, http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/03/n3613-static-if-considered discusses the idea of a `static if` in C++, and concludes that it "is fundamentally flawed, and its adoption would be a disaster for the language."

Comment: @akim Excellent comment, I wish this was still open so that you could add this as an answer. A more recent [update from Apr-10-'15](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4421.html#29) "SG8 isn't including it in their scope for the near future. Voutilainen is planning to write a simplified proposal for C++17" Ville Voutilainen did indeed write [proposal n4461](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4461.html) The latest is: "EWG encouraged the author to come back in Kona with a more detailed proposal."