# Generic lambda argument for std::pair

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to see if this is possible in the C++14 generic lambda, but I cannot find a right way to express it (or perhaps it is not possible). The simplified example is:

```
auto confirmOperation = [](auto pr){
  assert(pr.second);
};
```

The idea is that if you pass it an `std::pair` where the `second` is a `bool` (such as what is returned from `emplace` functions), it can look at this bool.

If this was a template parameter instead, I could explicitly show the `pair` with the types of the pair as generic, but I don't think that is possible with a lambda? Thus instead I mark the entire argument as generic, and thus the compiler doesn't seem able to deduce that I'm passing it the return of a map's `emplace()`.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Can you please show the surrounding code (i.e. with the map emplace included)?

Comment: What are you asking for here? `auto` *is* a generic type that can represent `pair`.Do you want to change the behavior of the function by the types in the return?

Comment: So, many people upvoted and favorited this.  If you can read the above and explain what you think the OP is saying, could you translate for me?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. In what way does it fail to satisfy what you need?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can constrain a lambda using `enable_if`:

```
auto confirmOperation = [](auto pr) ->
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(pr.second), bool>::value> {
  assert(pr.second);
};
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/g/ezuLC1).

Comment: Wow, that is some kung fu.

Comment: @ecatmur Yeah that.s why I used `decltype(pr.second)` in mine too ;)

Comment: While neat, how is this an answer to the OP's "question"?  In short, why do you think this is what the OP is asking?

Comment: @Yakk If you have some clarification on what the OP wants please enlighten us ([my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749044/generic-lambda-argument-for-stdpair/37749553#comment62968132_37749044) doesn't seem to be getting the job done.) Otherwise this is as good an answer as any. It's also been given the OP's [seal of kung fu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749044/generic-lambda-argument-for-stdpair/37749553#comment62969698_37749615) so that's gotta count for something.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an implementation details template function:

```
template<typename T>
void lambda_impl(std::pair<T, bool> const &p) {
  assert(p.second);
}
```

and then call this in your lambda as:

```
auto f = [](auto p) { lambda_impl(p); };
```

The following scheme may be available in the future with the advent of Concepts-Lite. For the time being it works only on GCC:

```
auto f = [](std::pair<auto, auto> const &p) { assert(p.second); };
```

or even better:

```
auto f = [](std::pair<auto, bool> const &p) { assert(p.second); };
```

P.S Clang is correct not to compile this due to the fact that `auto` parameters are not part of C++14.

Comment: This doesn't compile on clang with c++14 enabled

Comment: very pretty, but my Clang with -std=c++14 won't compile this. it says: `'auto' not allowed in template argument` and it underlines the first `auto` in the `pair` you have there

Comment: That's sad, because it compiles on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/288f843d3219dc07. Is that standard or a GCC extension?

Comment: I can only assume this is non-standard behavior?

Comment: Fails on MSVS2015 as well(I know not a really good tool to check for compliance).

Comment: From cppreference: "If auto is used as a type of a parameter, the lambda is a generic lambda. ". Since `auto` is not the type of a parameter, then it can't be a generic lambda. I think it's a neat feature, though.

Comment: @101010: Your "even better" is only valid with Concepts TS.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry everyone I corrected that I work with GCC and I forgot that auto parameters would be available in the future :)

Comment: @101010 Is that coming in C++1z?

Comment: @NathanOliver Look at the Concepts TS, which is unfortunately not part of C++17

Comment: @NathanOliver Last time I checked, Herb said that Concepts needs "more work" to make it on C++17

Comment: Bummer.  Thanks for the info guys

Comment: @KABoissonneault I thought Herb Sutter was saying that [if the standards committee would permit `static_if` we could have Concepts with C++17](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37553391/2642059), or has the standards committee officially nixed that?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could just use [`is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) here:

```
[](auto pr){
    static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(pr.second), bool>);
    assert(pr.second);
};
```

Or if C++17 is not an option, a message to `static_assert` is required and you won't be able to use `is_same_v`:

```
[](auto pr){
    static_assert(is_same<decltype(pr.second), bool>::value, "ouch");
    assert(pr.second);
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/t9Y08W)

Comment: Isn't `static_assert` without a message C++17 only? And what happens if `pr.second` is not a valid expression?

Comment: @KABoissonneault You're right. I've written a live example using only C++14. If `pr.second` is invalid then the `static_assert` will trigger. Which it seems like is what we wanted in the first place?