# generic lambda auto in parameter type template type

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, auto

I'm trying to figure out why clang is not compiling this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto lambda = [](const std::vector<auto>& x){
        std::cout << x.front() << x.back() << std::endl;
    };
    lambda(std::vector<int>(1,1));
}
```

According to this post [auto in pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749044/generic-lambda-argument-for-stdpair) it is not allowed by the C++14 Standard, but I could not find any sources to support that.
My understanding of the respective part of the standard is, that this feature should be allowed (Chapter 5.1.2 Clause 5 indicates that every auto is translated into a template parameter, independent of the exact positioning
(Quote: `consists of one invented type template-parameter for each occurrence of auto in the lambda’s parameter-declaration-clause`).

To avoid any later questions: no I don't have an actual Standard, but use a earlier Draft (N3797). I hope that they did not remove my interpretion.

Thank you!

Comment: `auto` is fine, `const auto` is fine, `const auto&` is fine; `const std::vector<auto>&` is not fine, as it relies on Concepts rather than standard C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding of the standard has to do with what `parameter-declaration-clause` permits. It is a list of `parameter-declaration`s. And that involves a lot of complex grammar.

But the end result of untangling that complex grammar is that `auto` cannot be used in a `template-argument-list`. And that's what you're trying to do when you use `vector<auto>`.

So 5.1.2 is irrelevant, since grammatically `auto` simply *cannot* be put there.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is forbidden by the grammar; `auto` is grammatically a *simple-type-specifier*, just like `bool` or `int`.

Answer (score 2):

"generic lambda" is defined in [[dcl.spec.auto]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.auto#3):

> If the `auto` *type-specifier* appears as one of the *decl-specifier*s
>   in the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *parameter-declaration* of a
>   *lambda-expression*, the lambda is a *generic lambda*.

The `auto` in `const std::vector<auto>& x` is not "one of the *decl-specifier*s
in the *decl-specifier-seq*", therefore `[](const std::vector<auto>& x){ }` is not a "generic lambda". Instead, per [[dcl.spec.auto]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.auto#6):

> A program that uses `auto` or `decltype(auto)` in a context not
>   explicitly allowed in this section is ill-formed.

Comment: You were less than *30 seconds* faster than me in finding that.